Loading Field Map file using ArcGIS Pro
I want to export the features with specified fields, which have been defined by myself.
Unfortunately, when I want to load my own .fieldmap file it doesn't work. ArcGIS Pro doesn't accept it and it returns to the beginning as you can see in this GIF attached below:

What is the reason behind it?


Looking at the field names, it looks like you are using an CAD file, is this the case? Try exporting the CAD file to a feature class then see if the field map works?

Is there any option in ArcGIS Pro to do so?

What export CAD to a feature class? Yes. tools are in the conversion toolbox (to geodatabase).
